# Github pages don't render images in my project built in Flutter after the last Flutter's update (2.10.1)

Tags: flutter, github-pages

Github pages don't render images
`Image(image:AssetImage('image.png'))` in my project built in Flutter after the last Flutter's update (2.10.1)... Has anyone else had this happen?

Comment: try with providing full path like `Image(image:AssetImage('assets/images/image.png'))`

Comment: Very very very thanks... now it works!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of [Yeasin Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157127/yeasin-sheikh) now works. You must add in the path: `Image(image:AssetImage('assets/images/image.png'))`